# After Next.js exporting static html, how can I judge whether to jump through Link or native a tag jump?

Tags: html, static, next.js

Condition: Export static html

How to recognize whether to jump by `next/link` or by `direct access` (that is, a tag access)?

I tried using `pageProps` with `useRouter` and `_app.tsx`, but both failed.

Help Me!

*Translated by Google*

Comment: Please get tour and read this article about how to ask question in stackoverflow : https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Next/App` component will not be unmounted for client-side transitions, you can track the previous `asPath` provided by the `useRouter` hook inside the `App` component exported from `_app.tsx`. If there is no previous `asPath`, then it is not client-side transitions.

> `asPath`: `String` - Actual path (including the query) shown in the browser

Possible implementation:

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]);
  return ref.current;
}

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  const { asPath } = useRouter();
  const previousAsPath = usePrevious(asPath);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!previousAsPath) {
      console.log('Direct access');
    } else {
      console.log(`Come from ${previousAsPath}`);
    }
  }, [previousAsPath]);
  return <Component {...pageProps} />
}

export default MyApp;
```